# While compressing the folder many other zip files creating during the process

Tags: linux, compression, zip

I seen a strange thing never seen before while compressing the folder into the zip.
When I start zipping my folder there are many zip files showing automatically during the process.

Like say the folder name is `user` when I compress user, then the `user.zip` is created near the folder but also there are many zip files

"creating and deleting or we can say appear of disappear"

automatically during the process. The zip files which are creating have a names like `ziSLAV`,`ziP8PLF`,`ziiSYAN` etc etc.

But these files appear only during compressing process, after that nothing happen.
Why is this happening I didn't understand.

I am using **Ubuntu**, but I never seen this in **Windows**.

Comment: You never saw this because the behavior is hidden by profile directories for temp files.

Comment: so these files always create during compressing either in linux or windows

Comment: Please rephrase your (comment) question